# splitting a string using words as delimiters

Tags: java, regex, string

I'm trying to take out special strings from a mother string using string.split in java with regular expressions.

```
string str = "name ching chang field computer engineering grade 9.98";
string[] splits = str.split("regex");
```

I want to use the words name, field and grade as delimiters. Now what should the regular expression be so that my string array (splits) has the following items in it:

```
splits[0] = "ching chang"  
splits[1] = "computer engineering"  
splits[2] = "9.98"
```

Comment: Grade isn't a delimiter here.. it won't split the way you want it.

Comment: use `split("name|field|grade")`

Answer (score 14):

```
String str = "name ching chang field computer engineering grade 9.98";
String[] splits = str.split("name |field |grade ");

//test with
for(String s : splits)
    System.out.println(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    String str = "name ching chang field computer engineering grade 9.98";
    String[] splits = str.split("name|field|grade");
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(splits));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

/**
 * Fieldsplitter with configurable fields
 */
public class FieldSplitter {

    private static Logger LOG = new Logger();

    /**
     * Test method
     * 
     * @param args
     *            not used
     */
    public static final void main(String[] args) {

        String[] fields = new String[] { "name", "field", "grade" };
        // regular test case
        printFieldValues(fields,
                "name ching chang field computer engineering grade 9.98");
        // missing field
        printFieldValues(fields,
                "ching chang field computer engineering grade 9.98");
        // duplicate field
        printFieldValues(fields,
                "name ching chang field computer engineering name johnny bravo grade 9.98");
    }

    /**
     * Gets the values of the fields from the input. If a field is not found the
     * value is null. If a field occurs multiple times the last value is used.
     * 
     * @param fields
     *            the known fields
     * @param input
     *            the input containing consecutive fields and their values
     *            separated by whitespace
     * @return a Map containing all known fields and their values
     */
    public static Map<String, String> getFieldValues(String[] fields,
            String input) {
        Map<String, String> fieldValues = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for (String field : fields) {
            fieldValues.put(field, null);
        }
        String[] words = input.split("\\s");
        LOG.debug("words:" + Arrays.toString(words));
        String field = null;
        int start = 0;
        for (String word : words) {
            if (fieldValues.containsKey(word)) {
                int end = input.indexOf(word, start);
                if (end < 0) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(String.format(
                            "Error: '%s' not found after position %s", word,
                            end));
                }
                if (field != null) {
                    fieldValues.put(field, input.substring(start, end));
                }
                field = word;
                start = end + word.length();
            }
        }
        if (field != null) {
            fieldValues.put(field, input.substring(start, input.length()));
        }
        return fieldValues;
    }

    private static void printFieldValues(String[] fields, String input) {
        for (Entry<String, String> field : getFieldValues(fields, input)
                .entrySet()) {
            LOG.debug(String.format("%s=%s", field.getKey(), field.getValue()));
        }
    }

    /** A simple logger */
    private static class Logger {
        void debug(String message) {
            System.out.println(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
words:[name, ching, chang, field, computer, engineering, grade, 9.98]
grade= 9.98
name= ching chang 
field= computer engineering 
words:[ching, chang, field, computer, engineering, grade, 9.98]
grade= 9.98
name=null
field= computer engineering 
words:[name, ching, chang, field, computer, engineering, name, johnny, bravo, grade, 9.98]
grade= 9.98
name= johnny bravo 
field= computer engineering
```

P.S. I just discovered a trivial but handy trick: In Eclipse select your code and press TAB to indent it. Then copy and paste the indented code into the Stackoverflow edit field. In this way the code will immediately render correctly.